# Playback GigE Vision camera stream captured with a network analyzer in PCAP format

Tags: pcap, gige-sdk

I have a RGB camera from Flir with a GigE vision interface connected via ethernet switch to both host and ethernet network logger that capture the transmissions in a pcap file format.
My question, is there a way or SW that allow to 'convert' the pcap data to a playable GigE vision format that can be opened in the camera SDK and present the stream?
I'm using Spinnaker SDK, Netgear4300 and Win10 OS.
I'd appreciate any help and guidness.